# hibernate criteria - querying tables in n:m relationship

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

I'm trying to build a query with hibernate criteria for the following scenario:

- Two entities: Indicator and report (each with their own tables, classes etc.)
- an indicator can be used in zero to many reports
- a report uses zero to many indicators
- therefore, I have an intersection table to store the relationship
- the relationship is defined in both classes and their hibernate mappings
- in the UI, the user can select one or many reports (among other things), and I would like to query the DB for the Indicators used in these reports

I've tried the following:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("Reports", selectedReports));
```

but all I get is a strange SQL Statement with

```
where this_.Indicator_ID in (?)
```

and then a JDBC exception (missing parameter)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Note: I've looked into [Querying ManyToManyrelationship with Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264339/querying-manytomany-relationship-with-hibernate-criteria), but the accepted solution there is to build a custom sql-string ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Indicator.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("someField", myObject).createCriteria("reports")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("reportName", name);
    c.list();
```

You need to create a sub criteria to the entity that is being held in a collection on some other entity.

```
String[] selectedReportsId = {"1", "2", "3"};
 c.add(Restrictions.eq("someField",myObject).createCriteria("reports")
    .add(Restrictions.in("id", selectedReportsId);
```

Then check out the bit about transforming the results from here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations

Also this may shed some light on what you can do w/ criteria:
http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Comment: Okay, this allows my to query fields of the report class - halfway there! But I have a Collection<Report> selectedReports that I'd like to use in my query ..

Comment: Thanks for the links ..
Any way to directly use the Collection<Report> I have? For a many-to-one property (e.g. Owner) I can simply use 
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("Owner", selectedOwners));

Comment: NO new news .. think I'll just accept this answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the "querycriteria-associations" link now returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you must, here are a couple of suggestions that Google came back with after searching for "hibernate hql many-to-many":

http://patf.net/blogs/index.php?blog=2&c=1&more=1&pb=1&tb=1&title=many_to_many_in_hql

And from the Hibernate forums:

http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2340747&sid=d4c8d2fcc16aed0201f73eb74619692a

And from the Spring forums:

http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=36870

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I'm trying to use Criteria (not HQL). I've tried to google, but no success so far ...

Comment: You ARE using HQL when you use Criteria, because it uses HQL behind the scenes: http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3322131

Comment: That may be true, but the code I'm trying to write does not use HQL directly. I may be stretching the limits, but I'd like to see how far I can take Criteria without reverting direct HQL (or SQL for that).

Comment: Very good, sorry I'm not more helpful.  I hope someone else can answer - we'll both learn something then.  Good luck.

Comment: I'll post if I figure something out .. zmf seems to be on the right track. Thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is how I got it to work (thanks to zmf).

```
Criteria subcrit = criteria.createCriteria("Reports");
Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction();
for (Reports r : selectedReports) {
    dis.add(Restrictions.idEq(r.getID()));
}
subcrit.add(dis);
```

This is almost exactly what zmf suggested, all I added was the disjunction to build the criteria from the Collection that is passed around.

All that's left to do is to try to use the collection directly ...