# Querying Many-To-Many relationship with Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, activerecord, nhibernate

I've the following many to many relation: `File 1 --- * File_Insurer * --- 1 Insurer`. I'm trying to query this relation using the Criteria API (Active Record) to get Files that meet ALL specified Insurers (Get all Files where `Insurer.Id == 2` AND `Insurer.Id == 3`).

***Mapping files (parts)***:

### File

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Insurer),
Table = "Insurer_File", ColumnKey = "IdFile", ColumnRef = "IdInsurer")]
public virtual IList<Insurer> Insurers
{
get { return insurers; }
set { insurers = value; }
}
```

### Insurer

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(File),
Table = "Insurer_File", ColumnKey = "IdInsurer", ColumnRef = "IdFile")]
public virtual IList<File> Files
{
get { return files; }
set { files = value; }
}
```

**I've tried many options**:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<File>();
dc.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
dc.CreateCriteria("Insurers").Add(Expression.Eq("Id", long.Parse("2")));
dc.CreateCriteria("Insurers").Add(Expression.Eq("Id", long.Parse("3")));
List<File> searchResults = File.FindAll(dc).ToList<File>();
```

That gives me an error: `duplicate association path: Insurers`.

**Next option**:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<File>();
dc.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
dc.CreateCriteria("Insurers").Add(Expression.And(Expression.Eq("Id", long.Parse("3")), Expression.Eq("Id", long.Parse("2"))));
List<File> searchResults = File.FindAll(dc).ToList<File>();
```

The result list is empty (but shouldn't be).

**Next option with alias**:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<File>();
dc.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
dc.CreateAlias("Insurers", "i").Add(Expression.Eq("i.Id", long.Parse("2"))).Add(Expression.Eq("i.Id", long.Parse("3")));
List<File> searchResults = File.FindAll(dc).ToList<File>();
```

The result list is empty again - strange.

**Next try**:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<File>();
dc.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
List<long> insurerIds = new List<long>();
insurerIds.Add(2);
insurerIds.Add(3);
dc.CreateCriteria("Insurers").Add(Expression.In("Id", insurerIds));
List<File> searchResults = File.FindAll(dc).ToList<File>();
```

This works somehow, but the result set contains a all possible options (OR) - it's not an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

This has been [answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264339/querying-manytomany-relationship-with-hibernate-criteria) - see my take on it below. The hibernate site seems to be down, but check out this copy of chapter 11, [HQL](http://www.kkaok.pe.kr/doc/hibernate/reference/html/queryhql.html), of the Hibernate user guide.

```
public List<Files> findFilesForInsurers(Insurer... insurers) {
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
    hql.append("select f from Files ff where 1=1 ");
    for (int i = 0; i < insurers.length; i++) {
        hql.append(String.format(" and :i%d in elements(ff.insurers)", i));
    }
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < insurers.length; i++) {
        query.setParameter("i" + i, insurers[i]);
    }
    return query.list();
}
```

Giving HQL like this:

```
select f from Files ff where 1=1
    and :i1 in elements(ff.insurers)
    and :i2 in elements(ff.insurers)
```

I suspect the SQL you are trying to achieve is something like this, although i couldn't tell you *exactly* what the above HQL translates into...

```
select f.* from files f
    left outer join files_insurers fi1 on fi1.files_id = f.id
    left outer join files_insurers fi2 on fi2.files_id = f.id
where 1 = 1
    and fi1.insurers_id = :i1
    and fi2.insurers_id = :i2;
```