# M to N mapping: query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
class Product {
    String name;
    Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<Label>();
    ...
}
```

and

```
class Label {
    String name;
    Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
    ...
}
```

Now I wonder how to query for those products which both has label 'A' and label 'B', in Hibernate.
Many thanks.

Comment: Look up the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: You should post your mapping files and query attempts in order to encourage people to help you

Comment: there is a similar question with an accepted answer. Take a look and let us know what have you tried... http://stackoverflow.com/a/313040/162300